# Button 404 on click with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working to change a button on specific pages. Not just the text that's inside it, but also where it goes. Currently, it's part of a form that is meant to add a product to cart. I need that to change though and simple take the user to the contact form.

The closest I've come is getting it to take users to the contact page, but it appears as a 404. Could this be because of the form's method? The URL matches the contact page exactly and I've tried both the full path and relative path. Here's the code I have so far:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".grid-link__meta:contains('$0.00')").html('<strong>Contact Us for Quote</strong>');
    $(".product-single__price:contains('$0.00')").text('');

  if ( $('.product-single__price').text() == "") {
    $("#AddToCartText:contains('Add to Cart')").html('<strong>Get Quote</strong>');
    $('#AddToCartForm').click(function(){
        $('#AddToCartForm').attr('action', '/pages/contact-us');
    });
  }
})
```

The code that's causing trouble is:

```
$('#AddToCartForm').click(function(){
    $('#AddToCartForm').attr('action', '/pages/contact-us');
});
```

edit: Here's the code that I'm trying to update. :

```
<form action="/cart/add" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="AddToCartForm">
        <select name="id" id="productSelect" class="product-single__variants">
              <option  selected="selected"  data-sku="" value="20267761543">Default Title - $0.00 USD</option>
        </select>

        <div class="product-single__quantity is-hidden">
          <label for="Quantity">Quantity</label>
          <input type="number" id="Quantity" name="quantity" value="1" min="1" class="quantity-selector">
        </div>

        <button type="submit" name="add" id="AddToCart" class="btn">
          <span id="AddToCartText">Add to Cart</span>
        </button>
      </form>
```

edit: SOLVED. Thanks to @Barmar for the idea of changing the button's form from POST to GET. There are still some things that get passed in the URL, but the form works fine.

Comment: 404 means the URL is wrong. Look in the browser's console to see the actual URL that it's using.

Comment: can you post the error? so we can also see a more detailed explanation. How can you say it matches exactly? have tried navigating to the page alone?

Comment: Shouldn't the click handler be on the button, not the form?

Comment: @Barmar The URL is correct. I've had the working contact page and 404 version up at the same time to compare. They're the same.

Comment: @Barmar I just changed that selector but still have the same issue.

Comment: Then check your server log, to see what it's receiving and why it's reporting an error.

Comment: i assume #AddToCartForm is a button. I don't understand why you assign the action inside the button instead of the form.

Comment: @Barmar I don't have a server log unfortunately. :( Developing on a shopify site.

bugscoder - I've tried both and they both produce the same issue. The form is just the button anyway in this case.

Comment: What happens if you change the method to `get`?

Comment: What's the URL in your browser's address bar when it says 404? It's probably that your `/pages/contact-us` is set up for `GET` requests, not `POST`, which is what your form is telling it to use.

Comment: @Barmar That worked! Thanks!!

All I had to do was add the following:
    $("#AddToCartForm").attr("method", "get");